# I am trying to detect changes on a particular element using the MutationObserver but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have been trying to log the updated cost information from an HTML document but have not been successful. I am sure it has to be that I am not using the mutation observer correctly. The js file is linked. Below is the HTML element that I am targeting.

HTML:

`<span id="cost">0.00</span>`

The JS file contains the following code:

```
const total = document.getElementById('cost');

console.log(total);
const options = {
  characterData: true
};

function logCallback(mutations) {
  console.log('called');

  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    if (mutation.type === 'characterData')
    {
      console.log('Mutation Detected: Price changed');
    }
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(logCallback);

observer.observe(total.childNodes[0], options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work **if** the code that was making the change changed the text node you're watching rather than destroying and replacing it, like this:

```
total.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "1.00";
```

Live Example:

```js
const total = document.getElementById('cost');

const options = {
  characterData: true,
};

function logCallback(mutations) {
  console.log('called');

  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    if (mutation.type === 'characterData')
    {
      console.log('Mutation Detected: Price changed');
    }
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(logCallback);

observer.observe(total.childNodes[0], options);

// Code that changes the element
total.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "1.00";
```

```html
<span id="cost">0.00</span>
```

But the code making the change is probably destroying and replacing the child node, like this:

```
total.innerText = "1.00";
```

To handle that, you're probably best off watching for `childList` changes on the `total` element itself:

```js
const total = document.getElementById('cost');

const options = {
  childList: true,
};

function logCallback(mutations) {
  console.log('called');

  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    console.log('Mutation Detected: Price changed');
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(logCallback);

observer.observe(total, options);

// Code that changes the element
total.innerText = "1.00";
```

```html
<span id="cost">0.00</span>
```

You may need to refine that (I removed the `if` checking only for `characterData` changes), and/or combine it with what you already had (in case some other code changes the text differently), but that's the main issue with what you had.